# How can I extract a subset from a column/field using awk?

Tags: bash, awk

I wondered how can I extract a subset from a column/field using awk?

Here is the input file test.txt:

```
aaa bbb ccc=0.7707;ddd=0.21
```

I would like to be able to extract figure "0.21" from the 3rd column, and output it with the 1st and 2nd columns:

```
aaa bbb 0.21
```

I have tried and used the code below but failed:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "\t" } { $4 = /^ddd=(+\d)/ ; print $1,$2,$4 }' test.txt
```

Please help!

Many thanks,
TP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `gsub`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "\t" } { gsub(/.*=/, "", $3); print $1,$2,$3 }' text.txt
```

For your input, it'd give:

```
aaa bbb 0.21
```

Comment: Great! It works perfectly! I changed it to gsub(/.*ddd=/, "", $3) in order to futher extract numbers from "ccc", but it doesn't work for gsub(/.*ccc=.*/, "", $3). I wondered can you tell me more aobut hwat is ".*" and how do you extract numbers from "ccc". Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user2975959 You can try saying: `awk '{ a=gensub(/ccc=([^;]*).*/, "\\1", "g", $3); gsub(/.*/, a, $3); print $1,$2,$3 }' filename`

Comment: @devnull Its important to mention that `gensub` is `gnu awk` command.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify multiple delimiters using the `-F` flag or setting `FS` in the `BEGIN` block. For example:

```
echo "aaa bbb ccc=0.7707;ddd=0.21" | awk -F "[ =]" '{ print $1, $2, $NF }'
```

Results:

```
aaa bbb 0.21
```

Comment: When its only two filed separators, you can do `-F" |="`

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk`

```
awk '{split($3,a,"=");print $1,$2,a[3]}'
aaa bbb 0.21
```

Comment: Excellent! I then use 2 splits to extract numbers for ccc: awk '{ split($3, a, "ccc="); split(a[2], b, ";"); print $1,$2,b[1] }' test.vcf. Thanks a lot!